# mysql get maser and all details if one detail matches condition

Tags: mysql

i have two tables `product` and `specs` i want to get the product and a group_concat(all specs) if at least one spec matches the WHERE.
this is what i have so far but it only returns the one spec that matches WHERE.

```
select p.ID, p.name, p.manufacturer GROUP_CONCAT(s.specValue order by s.pID,',')
from product as p
JOIN spec AS s ON p.ID = s.pID
WHERE s.specValue = 'micro'
group by p.ID
```

---

```
product table 
| ID | name   | manufacturer |
| 1  | Iphone |   apple      |
| 2  | galaxy |   samsung    |
| 3  | note   |   samsung    |
------------------------------
spec table
| ID | pID | specName | specVlaue |
| 1  |  1  |  charger |   bad     |
| 2  |  2  |  charger |   micro   |
| 3  |  2  |  keypad  |  touch    |
| 4  |  4  |  charger |  micro    |
-----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following which uses a `IN` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select p.ID, 
  p.name, 
  p.manufacturer,
  GROUP_CONCAT(s.specValue order by s.pID,',') AllSpecs
from product as p
JOIN spec AS s 
  ON p.ID = s.pID
WHERE p.ID in (select pID
               from spec s1
               where s1.specValue = 'micro')
group by p.ID
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7dac/7).

Or you can use `EXISTS`:

```
select p.ID, 
  p.name, 
  p.manufacturer,
  GROUP_CONCAT(s.specValue order by s.pID,',') AllSpecs
from product as p
JOIN spec AS s 
  ON p.ID = s.pID
WHERE exists (select pID
               from spec s1
               where s1.specValue = 'micro'
                 and p.ID = s1.pid)
group by p.ID
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7dac/8)

Both give the result:

```
| ID |   NAME | MANUFACTURER |    ALLSPECS |
--------------------------------------------
|  2 | galaxy |      samsung | touch,micro |
```

If you don't want to use a subquery, you could use a `HAVING` clause to filter records with the value:

```
select p.ID, 
  p.name, 
  p.manufacturer,
  GROUP_CONCAT(s.specValue order by s.pID,',') AllSpecs
from product as p
JOIN spec AS s 
  ON p.ID = s.pID
group by p.ID
having GROUP_CONCAT(s.specValue order by s.pID,',') like '%micro%'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7dac/16)

Comment: @user616606 the only way is to use a `HAVING` clause -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7dac/16